# when reference variable is assigned an object we call that variable object and not reference variable?

Tags: java, object, reference

GUI g1; //here it is a reference variable
g1=new GUI(); //now that reference variable becomes object

Can we say that g1 is reference variable and object at the same time.

Comment: `g1` is a reference variable that refers to an object.

Comment: g1 just holds or points to the reference or address where the actual GUI object is.
g1 is a variable whose value is the address of the GUI object.
So, g1 is not the object, its reference to the instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GUI g1
```

At this point g1 is a reference that can point to a GUI

```
g1=new GUI();
```

At this point a new instance of a GUI is created and g1 references it.